# Excel sending emails to all people in one Column, need to email only person in specific cell. How?

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am creating a spreadsheet that will email supervisors 30, 15, and 7 days before the a report is due.  Everything is working, except it is sending emails to everyone in Column L and not the designated person in Column L.

[image]

Please help. I have copied and pasted the code below.

```
Public Sub GetDates()
    Dim rw As Integer
    Dim subj As String
    rw = 2

    With ActiveSheet

       Do Until .Range("A" & rw) = ""
            If .Range("M" & rw) = "" Then
                If DateAdd("D", 30, Date) = .Range("G" & rw) Then
                    Call SendEmail(Range("A" & rw), Range("B" & rw), 30, Range("L" & rw), False)
                ElseIf DateAdd("D", 15, Date) = .Range("G" & rw) Then
                    Call SendEmail(Range("A" & rw), Range("B" & rw), 15, Range("L" & rw), False)
                ElseIf DateAdd("D", 7, Date) = .Range("G" & rw) Then
                    Call SendEmail(Range("A" & rw), Range("B" & rw), 7, Range("L" & rw), False)
                End If
            End If

            If Day(Date) = 1 And .Range("G" & rw) < Date And .Range("M" & rw) = "" Then
                subj = subj & .Range("A" & rw) & ", " & .Range("B" & rw) & "--" & .Range("C" & rw) & " Report Past Due" & vbCrLf
            End If
            rw = rw + 1

        Loop

        If subj <> "" Then
            Call SendEmail(subj, "", 0, "supervisor@company.com", True)
            Call SendEmail(subj, "", 0, "aothersupervisor@company.com", True)
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub SendEmail(lName As String, fName As String, nDays As Integer, sTo As String, LastEmail As Boolean)

    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Flds As Variant



    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

     iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
        Set Flds = iConf.Fields
        With Flds
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") _
                           = "server"
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
            .Update
        End With

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Columns("L").Cells
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
            Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .to = cell.Value
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .From = """Report Due"" <donotreply@company.com>"
        .Subject = "Report Due"
        .HTMLBody = lName & ", " & fName & "  <a href='http://www.website.com'>Probation Report</a> / <a href='http://www.website.com'>IDP Report</a> Due in " & nDays & " days"
        .Send
            End With
            Set iMsg = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if intentional, but some `Range()`s *don't* have the `.` preceding it for use with the `With` statement. (like the lines starting `Call SendEmail`).  That might be helpful to fix up.

Comment: How do you determine who is the designated person?

Comment: Sorceri (love the name):The person in Column L, Row 2, 3, 4, and so on is the supervisor. It might be supervisor@company.com in one row and supervisor2@company.com in the next one.  Batman, err Bruce Wayne: I will give that a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `SendEmail` subroutine you never use the Column L email parameter, `sTo`, and instead routine iterates through every cell in Column L:

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Columns("L").Cells
     ...
Next cell
```

Remove this `For` loop and use `sTo`:

```
If sTo Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .to = sTo
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .From = """Report Due"" <donotreply@company.com>"
        .Subject = "Report Due"
        .HTMLBody = lName & ", " & fName & "  <a href='http://www.website.com'>Probation Report</a> / <a href='http://www.website.com'>IDP Report</a> Due in " & nDays & " days"
        .Send
    End With

    Set iMsg = Nothing
End If
```

---

By the way, in your `GetDates` subroutine, consider using [Select Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) over the repeated `ElseIf` for readability as you have multiple conditions to manage:

```
Select Case .Range("G" & rw)

    Case DateAdd("D", 30, Date)
        Call SendEmail(Range("A" & rw), Range("B" & rw), 30, Range("L" & rw), False)

    Case DateAdd("D", 15, Date)
        Call SendEmail(Range("A" & rw), Range("B" & rw), 15, Range("L" & rw), False)

    Case DateAdd("D", 7, Date)
        Call SendEmail(Range("A" & rw), Range("B" & rw), 7, Range("L" & rw), False)

End Select
```

Alternatively, even shorter:

```
Select Case .Range("G" & rw) - Date

    Case 7, 15, 30
        Call SendEmail(Range("A" & rw), Range("B" & rw), _
                       .Range("G" & rw) - Date, Range("L" & rw), False)

End Select
```

Comment: I had a death in the family and just saw this today!!! Thank you soooooo much!!!! I really appreciate your help. You, Parfait, are awesome. You know that already, don't you? :)

Comment: Haha...many thanks, Amber! Glad to help but sorry for your loss.